# Topological sort by arcs

Tags: algorithm, topological-sort

Really need just some guidance :
Topological sort by arcs definition (from my question) - is a way of ordering all the arcs in directional graph so all arcs that insert to vertex must apear before the one that come out from this vertex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to to change anything in topological sort, you can just use it, and post-process.

high level pseudo code:

1. run topological sort, let the resulting array be `arr`
2. create empty edges list, let it be `l`
3. for each vertex `v` in `arr` [ordered iteration]:

       3.1. for each `(v,u)` in `E`:

          3.1.1. append `(v,u) to l`
4. return `l`

The advantage of this method is you can **use topological sort as black box, without modifying it** and just post-process to get the desired result.

**Correctness** [sketch of proof]:

Since for each edge `(v,u)` - `u` appears after `v` in topological sort, when you print it, it is done via `v`, and thus `(v,u)` is printed before you print any vertex attached to `u`.

**Complexity**:

`O(|V|+|E|)` topological sort, `O(|V|+|E|)` for post processing [iterating all vertices and all edges].

Comment: @OndrejKupka: Indeed, the constant will be higher then modifying topological sort [though not double I believe due to cache performance], but for the benefit of **encapsulating** topological sort. [which is very important aspect!]. In real life applications, *if you find out this part is a hot-spot*, you will probably want to rewrite it, agreed.

Comment: Yes, it's not really practical to copy so much code for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

"Traditional" topological sort is sorting vertices, while this one is sorting arcs. Otherwise the principle is the same...

Comment: I know but when i look in topological sort algorithm I don't understart how it can be changed for arcs...
Don't want you to solve it for me but I need some guidance please

Comment: Go to the wiki page you passed, opcode section. Drop `insert n into L` and at the step saying `remove edge e from the graph` do also `insert edge e into L`. This way you will remember arcs instead of vertices.